# Azure Mobile App Service - StorageController routing does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

Mobile service works fine when we hit TableControllers. But even after setting up all required parameters and configuration for StorageController type of controllers - we are not able to connect with them.

While we try to call those GET methods (E.G: https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/New_Monitoring_Data/{id}/MobileServiceFile)
we get following response:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

We doubt the routing on those controller is working or picked up by the mobile service and need help fixing it.

Here is app's Startup configuration:

```
    new MobileAppConfiguration()
        .MapApiControllers()
        .AddTables(                               // from the Tables package
            new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
                .MapTableControllers()
                .AddEntityFramework()             // from the Entity package
            )
        .ApplyTo(config);
```

One of the Storage controller class which we are not able to call (tried using PostMan - Get request)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Files;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Files.Controllers;
using FieldEngineer.DataObjects;

namespace FieldEngineer.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("tables/New_Monitoring_Data")]
    public class New_Monitoring_DataStorageController : StorageController<New_Monitoring_Data>
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{id}/StorageToken")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostStorageTokenRequest(string id, StorageTokenRequest value)
        {
            StorageToken token = await GetStorageTokenAsync(id, value);

            return Request.CreateResponse(token);
        }

        // Get the files associated with this record
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}/MobileServiceFiles")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFiles(string id)
        {
            IEnumerable<MobileServiceFile> files = await GetRecordFilesAsync(id);

            return Request.CreateResponse(files);
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("{id}/MobileServiceFiles/{name}")]
        public Task Delete(string id, string name)
        {
            return base.DeleteFileAsync(id, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your Startup file?

Comment: public partial class Startup
    {
        public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);


            Database.SetInitializer<FieldEngineerContext>(null);

            app.UseWebApi(config);

Comment: So no. Does it go after "            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);"

Comment: I generally put it before the MobileAppConfiguration().  I don't think it matters though.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working, but I was trained to but underscores in my table names, which is another problem. When will Azure SQL SaaS be more like regular SQL?